# Изменение цветов точек в scatterplot на основе третьего столбца

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scatter

На основе двух столбцов pandas DataFrame построил scatterplot, но нужно изменить цвет точек на основе третьего столбца + легенда графика должна показывать эти значения с соответствующими цветами. В третьем столбце всего три переменные в формате str.

```
plt.scatter(data['experience'], data['salary'])

plt.scatter(data['age'], data['salary']);

plt.xlabel('Age');
plt.ylabel('Salary');
```

Это только разделяет график на два по оси X. Если добавить в scatter с=data['experience'] выйдет ошибка несоответствия размеров.

График строится по столбцам salary(y) и age(x), а по столбцу experience нужно изменить цвет точек и добавить легенду.

Comment: пример исходных данных приведите (датафрейм)

Comment: Пример данных в вопсроизводимом виде надо приводить. как я на вашей фотографии свой код тестировать буду?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, у вас есть датафрейм:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({"salary":[43003, 22172, 15197, 42511, 17813], "experience":[">5", "3-5", "3-5", "<3", "3-5"], "age":[29,28, 28, 24,27]})
```

```
   salary experience  age
0   43003         >5   29
1   22172        3-5   28
2   15197        3-5   28
3   42511         <3   24
4   17813        3-5   27
```

тогда можно сделать так:

```
colidx=data.groupby("experience").grouper.group_info[0].tolist()
colors=["blue", "red", "green"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(data["age"], data["salary"], c=[colors[x] for x in colidx])

plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]